# Delete all non-end point vertices in a line ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have some culvert polylines that were collected and I would like them to be straight without having to manually delete the vertices between end points. Is there a tool to do this for the whole shapefile without Python.

Comment: I suppose you could select start- and endpoint by an expression, save them to a new layer and then convert these points back to lines.

Comment: Perhaps simplify with a huge tolerance. It should not remove the start and end points.

Comment: You might look at the Feature Vertices to Points tool to look for start and end points or perhaps dangle points.

Comment: Check out [Simplify By Straight Lines and Circular Arcs](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/simplifybystraightlinesandcirculararcs.htm). With the right parameters, this should take care of it for you.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I will look into those options. I am so glad I joined this chat room today!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or drawing showing what you want to do?